# tangent lines through points of a complete intersection curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a smooth complex algebraic curve which is a complete intersection of surfaces of degree $d_1$ and $d_2$ in $\mathbb P^3$.(both $d_i >3$)

Then my question is the following : Can we always choose $n$ number of points $p_1,..p_n \in C$ for any $n$ such that the tangent lines to $C (\subset \mathbb P^3)$ at all those points are not pairwise coplanar? and If it's not true for any $n$ then can we give an upper or lower bound for such $n$?

I have an example which says for a curve which is a complete intersection of a smooth quartic and cubic surface in $\mathbb P^3$ the above statement is true for $n=2$. But I am not able to see what happens in general context.

Any help from anyone is welcome

Comment: First, I presume you meant $d_i>1$, otherwise clearly this is impossible. Second, your question is a bit ambiguous. Do you want any pair of the $n$ tangent lines to be non-coplanar or did you mean something else?

Comment: @Mohan, If we require any pair of $n$ tangent lines to be coplanar, then will it imply for those $n$ points $p_1,....,p_n$, one has $h^0(\mathcal O_C(1)(-2p_1-..-2p_n)) =0$ ? .I forgot to mention that $d_i>3$.

Comment: I used non-coplanar and you use in the comment coplanar, confusing me further.

Comment: @Mohan,  extremely sorry. As you said it's non-coplanar. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true and has nothing to do with the curve being a complete intersection.

Let $C$ be a smooth complex space curve not contained in any hyperplane. Let $p\in C$ be a point and $l$ the tangent line at $p$. Projecting from this line, we get a morphism $\pi:C\to\mathbb{P}^1$, which is dominant since $C$ is not contained in any hyperplane and thus finite. Let $B\subset \mathbb{P}^1$ denote the union of the branch locus of $\pi$ and the images of all points in $l\cap C$. If $q\not\in \pi^{-1}(B)$, I claim that the tangent line at $q$ to $C$ doest not meet $l$ and thus they can not be coplanar. (I will leave this to you to check).

The rest is clear. Assume you have found $p_1,\ldots, p_{n-1}$ with the required property. For each $p_i$, from the previous paragraph, we only have finitely many points on $C$ whose tangent lines are coplanar with the tangent line at $p_i$. Avoiding these finitely many points for each $p_i$, we find a $p_n$ so that $p_1,\ldots, p_n$ satisfy what you need.

Comment: Could you please explain what 'Projecting from this line" mean? i.e. what is the precise definition of the map $\pi$? and Could you please indicate references for some of the facts used in the above proof?

Comment: @User If $x,y,z,t$ are the coordinates of 3- space, we may assume the line is given by $z=t=0$. Then, outside the line we have a morphism $(x,y,z,t)\mapsto (z,t)\in \mathbb{P}^1$ which gives a map from your curve minus points on the line to the projective line. This extends to the whole curve since the curve is smooth.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I have one doubt. When you say $q \notin \pi^{-1}(B)$, then $q \in \pi^{-1}(Y-B)$ which means  either $q$ is inverse image of unramified points and hence has finitely many possibilities plus it can't be $l \cap C$. So how such $q$ are infinitely many? And why in the next paragraph we have for each $p_i$ only finitely many points whose tangent lines are coplanar to $p_i$?

Comment: @User There are infinitely many such $q$s or have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: do you mean $\pi^{-1}(Y-B)$ is infinite? Could you explain a little bit why is that so? I thought since some part of $Y-B$ is made up of unramified points, their inverse image could only give finitely many points. Please correct me if this is wrong way of looking at it. It will also be very helpful to me if you can give a hint for the  finite choice argument in the last paragraph of your main answer.

Comment: @User $Y-B$ is infinite, so its inverse image is infinite.